# Configuring JanusGraph to use Lucene via Java

Tags: java, lucene, janusgraph

I am trying to connect to JanusGraph using the following code:

```
Graph graph = GraphFactory.open(new PropertiesConfiguration("janusgraph.propertes");
```

Where my `janusgraph.properties` file is as follows:

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1

cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

index.janusgraph-index.backend=lucene
```

However, when I try to connect I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
    at uk.gov.nca.cdp.graphutils.server.controllers.MergeGraph.lambda$merge$0(MergeGraph.java:26)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find implementation class: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:61)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:464)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:149)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1897)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:136)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:164)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:133)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:113)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:56)
    ... 16 more
```

This sounds like it's trying to use Elasticsearch rather than Lucene. How do I correctly configure it to use Lucene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that your configuration does not define a `storage.hbase.table` so the default table name `janusgraph` is used (see the [JanusGraph configuration reference](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/config-ref.html#_storage_hbase)). An HBase table named `janusgraph` must have been previously created with Elasticsearch for the indexing provider. JanusGraph stores its initial configuration in the HBase table, so when you connect to the `janusgraph` table, it is reading the old properties from the `janusgraph` table. You should either:

- Drop the existing `janusgraph` HBase table. From the HBase shell: `disable 'janusgraph'; drop 'janusgraph';`
- Use a different HBase table by setting `storage.hbase.table=mygraph`

As described in the [JanusGraph Lucene documentation](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/lucene.html), the Lucene indexing backend requires two parameters in its configuration:

- `index.[X].backend=lucene`
- `index.[X].directory=/data/searchindex`

where `[X]` is the name of the index. You could set this to match the directory name, `searchindex`, or `search` as commonly found in examples, or `janusgraph-index` as in your question. Make sure you include both configuration properties.